# Non-printable characters in answer?

Tags: support, answers

This mostly applies to [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) questions.

Is it allowed to use non-printable characters in answers? This effectively makes the answer a string of bytes.

If yes, how is the answer supposed to be supplied, considering that non-printable characters won't be correctly displayed?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use binary answers. Provide a hexdump of your solution if it's otherwise ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe hosting the binary file as a download for easy verification is handy too? You can for example create a gist, clone it, change the file to your binary file, and push. This would of course be in addition to the hexdump so the answer stays self-contained.

Comment: That's an optional extra, but make sure your solution remains valid if the download site is down.

Comment: I was already editing that in :)